# calling remote pages causing problem?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I Am getting this error while loading remote file in my page using ajax .

Missing Controller

Error: CbcController could not be found.

Error: Create the class CbcController below in file: app/controllers/cbc_controller.php

```
<?php
class CbcController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Cbc';
}
?>
```

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks..

Comment: You are not providing enough information at all. What is the ajax call? And what is the URL you are trying to call?

Comment: I'd create a `Cbc` controller.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the question you asked a little later, which I answered.

[Solving Dual URL Problem..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368754/solving-dual-url-problem)