# Solving Dual URL Problem..?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

I am using cakephp I have 2 links:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1" onclick="base_load_demo1('http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/');" >beer</a>
<a href="#" tabindex="2" onclick="base_load_demo('http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/cocktail/main/');">cocktail</a>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
var Url1 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/cocktail/main/";
var Url2 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/";
var Url3 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/mini/";

function base_load_demo(Url) {
  remoteCall(Url1,"","mainLeftContent");
  //remoteCall("SCRIPT_PATH","QUERY_STRING","TARGET_FUNCTION");
}

function base_load_demo1(Url2) {
  remoteCall(Url2,"","mainLeftContent");
  //remoteCall("SCRIPT_PATH","QUERY_STRING","TARGET_FUNCTION");
}
```

When I click on the first link it's showing its content through ajax call but when I click on the second link its giving error as follows:

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: Http:Controller could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class Http:Controller below in file: app/controllers/http:controller.php

```
<?php
class Http:Controller extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Http:';
}
?>
```

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp

and in FireFox console tab

> POST http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/cocktail/main/

How can we solve this dual URL calling at the same time?

```
var xmlHttp;
var uri = "";
var callingFunc = "";
var sResponse = new Array();



function remoteCall(sUrl, sQueryStr, sCalledBy)
{
    alert(sUrl);
    var resStr = "";
var str = " { ";
if(sQueryStr != "") {
    var arr1 = new Array();
    arr1 = sQueryStr.split("&");
    if(arr1){
        for(i=0;i<=arr1.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr1[i] && arr1[i] != "") 
                              {
                var arr2 = new Array();
                arr2 = arr1[i].split("=");
                str += arr2[0]+":'"+arr2[1]+"' ,";
                
              }
        }
    }
}                   

    str += " tp: 'tp' } ";
      
      
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",     
        url: sUrl,
        data: sQueryStr,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+sCalledBy).html(data);
            //jih(sCalledBy,data);
        }
    });
      
  /*    $.get(sUrl,sQueryStr,function(data) {   
    jih(sCalledBy,data);
    });*/
}

function jih(divid,data)
{
         if(document.getElementById(divid))
                     document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=data;
    }
```

Comment: Please **indent code by 4 spaces**, otherwise it's hard to read or not visible. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: ok but for now what is the solution..........

Comment: Have you read your own question? Did it make sense? No, because half your code is hidden. How do you expect to get an answer?

Comment: did you configure your routes file for the second link ?

Comment: Based on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308471), I'm guessing you've got a problem with your `base_load_demo` JavaScript function. What's the difference between `base_load_demo` and `base_load_demo1`? Can you show us that code?

Comment: but second link is not in that folder its some remote pages ....

Comment: Is `http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/...` the actual URL it's going to, or is that just a copy and paste problem in the question?

Comment: var Url1 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/cocktail/main/";
var Url2 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/";
var Url3 = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/mini/";


function base_load_demo(Url)
{
 remoteCall(Url1,"","mainLeftContent"); //remoteCall("SCRIPT_PATH","QUERY_STRING","TARGET_FUNCTION");
} 

function base_load_demo1(Url2)
{

 remoteCall(Url2,"","mainLeftContent"); //remoteCall("SCRIPT_PATH","QUERY_STRING","TARGET_FUNCTION");
}

Comment: could u pls copy this code form the comment into your poste and formate it? thx

Comment: Ok rajesh, that code looks fine and I've added it to your question for you. So please edit your question again to include the latest code for the `remoteCall` function.

Comment: @rajesh 4 spaces, it's not that hard. Select the code and press the '101010' button in the toolbar above the textarea.

Comment: can any  body tell me the solution

Comment: I didn't really get past the misuse of variables.. your onclick to base_load_demo() specifies a hardcoded URL, and yet, elsewhere in the code you've defined Url1 = ''. Not to mention, base_load_demo1 actually uses the variable that's passed to it, whereas regardless of what you pass to base_load_demo() it will ALWAYS use Url1.

Answer (score 1):

After your first call to either of those pages it loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/cocktail/main/js/common.js"></script>
```

in the header. Inside common.js is a function called **remoteCall**, which is overwriting your local remoteCall function.

The remoteCall function inside common.js adds

```
var url= WIDGET_WEG_PATH+scr_url;
```

where **WIDGET_WEG_PATH = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/"**

and **scr_url = "http://www.boxyourtvtrial.com/widget/beer/main/"**  (the first parameter of the new remoteCall function)

This is why you are getting the url 'doubled' in the post.

**Solution:**

Rename local remoteCall function to something that is distinct.